# request.params item disappearing after postback

Tags: asp.net, parameters, request

I have an ASP.net application that has a request item, which is disappearing after several postbacks. The postbacks are just for validation and ajax calls. The session is not resetting as I still have ~60 items in the params collection.

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps that the values that are disappearing were added to the collection by a form POST and that a subsequent call is making GET requests (through AJAX etc.)? The params collection is different to the "session" object in that it exists within the context of the current HttpRequest.